# Azure Managed Service Identity option disabled on Linux Web app service

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, service-principal, azure-managed-identity

[image]

I am trying to enable MSI on Linux Web app service using ARM template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, web app on Linux does not support Managed service identity. So, you could not use ARM template to do this.

Supported service you could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-overview#which-azure-services-support-managed-service-identity).

Note: Azure App Service is supported, but web app on Linux currently does not support msi.

Comment: Thank you. Shengbao Shui

Answer (score 1):

Update for anyone happening across this.

[It's supported now.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availablility-of-managed-identity-for-linux-in-app-service-and-functions/)